# Add a unique snapshot version upon copying resources with filtering

Tags: maven, resources, filter, snapshot, buildnumber-maven-plugin

When copying resources with filtering in Maven, I want to add the unique snapshot version to a resource file.

I have enabled filtering:

```xml
...
<name>My Application</name>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      ...
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

This is my resource file:

```
application.name=${name}
application.Version=${version}
```

After running `mvn resources:resources`, this is the result:

```
application.name=My Application
application.Version=0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

But what I actually want is this:

```
application.name=My Application
application.Version=0.1-20120310.143733-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 2.1.0-M1, Maven supports special syntax to get build timestamp in pom.xml, check out the doc [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables):

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd.HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

Alternatively, you can use [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html).